# I need this code to output the information in this format: "$variablename is of (datatype) data type, and its value is of x" Its not working

Tags: php

The first $variablename needs to be the variables actual name, not its value.

```
<?php
$name = "Bob";
    $stringVar = "$name";
$age = "17";
    $intVar = "$age";
$atarRequired = 69.45;
    $floatVar = "$atarRequired";
$atarAchieved = true;
    $boolVar = "$atarAchieved";
$courseSelected = NULL;
    $nullVar = "$courseSelected";

echo($stringVar "is of" gettype($name) "data type, and its value is" $name);

?>
```

Comment: Either escape `$stringVar = "\$name";` or use single-quotes `$stringVar = '$name';` Also, you'll need to concatenate `.` in the `echo`.

Comment: Or use commas `,` to separate in the `echo`.